# PHP ajax image upload multiplies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

Spent whole night with this script

but cant fix the bug. 
the problen here is,
say if i select an image and click upload it uploads current image file
then if i select another image and click upload it upload 2 new files with previous uploaded one too
and it increase every time
is there a good idea to solve the problem?

here is my [sourcecode](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-nOgxAcSg6BbmNLdEY4Z3RWdGM)

Comment: What increase every time?

Comment: Please update your question to include the code in question instead of linking it off-site.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to solve your problem: reload the page after success message:

(index.php, line 67, add a reload script);